# Spending a night in UAE dunes

Tags: dubai, uae, camping, deserts

I'm offered a camping option to spend a night directly in desert and dunes near Dubai ([Al Qudra Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Qudra_Lake)).

Should I have any concern about animals or species (scorpions, ants or other insects) or is there any thing specific, that I should take special care off, when planning such over-night stay there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should wear your shoes at all times. There could be scorpions. Problems aren't happening so often with those but you'd better be on the safe side.

This post gives a good overview of all the risks you might be facing there :
http://www.thenational.ae/news/uae-news/desert-survival-please-do-not-touch-the-scorpions